# Very Advanced Method/Constructor (Java) - Accepting Real Polymorphic Arguments - Sintax

Tags: methods, arguments, instanceof, polymorphism, implements

Is there any way to declare a polymorphic constructors? (please it is not overloading!).

I want to specify an argument that is isntanceof 1 class and 1 interface but I DONT WAN'T to create a new class with these both (class implements interface).

I want to declare a constructor, that is normally with syntax:

```
class Clas {
  public Clas(Object obj) { ... }
}
```

but these argument "obj" is instance of Class1 and Interface2, that i imagine like this:

```
class CubeRotationThread {
  public CubeRotationThread(Cube c implements IRotable) {...}
  //...or...
  public CubeRotationThread(Cube c instanceof IRotable) {...}
}
```

...or any other syntax that specify polymorphic only for this argument. I don't want to create the class: CubeRot extends Cube implements IRotable, because not all cubes have these work. And I don't want the other option of casting (Cube) CubeRot, for the inverse, making all cube rotables.
Perhaps IRotator can be implemented or not in cube or in other class.

I don't want then to use checking in the constructor:

```
if (obj instanceof Class) { myMethod(); }
```

I don't want to create a new class

```
class CubeRotatorThread extends Cube implements IRotator {
}
```

...because not all cubes can rotate and not only the cubes implements rotations.

I don't want to use generic class:

```
class CubeRotatorThread T extends Cube implements IRotator {
}
```

...because T is a class, and I want a object/argument.

And I don't want to create an `NotImplementsRotationException` too! for throw.

I want a polymorphic argument, I want a real polymorphic method

IS IT POSSIBLE? I searched it but I didn't find the syntax to do this in the constructor.

I saw in another codes from other language (probably C# or C++), help docs or definition docs, like:

```
Constructor(Class1 (Class2) args);
```

This is strange for me. And I'm not sure about this is that I want.

If the polymorphic constructor doesn't exist I think Oracle must create it. It is very useful.

```
class CubeRotationThread {
    public CubeRotationThread(Cube arg implements IRotator) {}
    public CubeRotationThread(Cube arg extends IRotator) {}
    public CubeRotationThread(Cube arg instanceof IRotator) {}
}
```

Comment: sorry for the dirt document, it is my first

Answer (score 0):

```
GENERIC METHOD
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html

I FOUND IT ! :)

    public <Q extends Class1 & Iterf2 & Interf3> Return Method(Q Object) { }

Q is the private mixture class you want with Extends & implements & implements...

here is with multiple objects:


    public <Q extends Class1 & Iterf2 & Interf3, W extends Class2 & Inter1 & Inter2> Return Method(Q arg1, W arg2) { }



use commas to separate classes inside <>, and use & to inherit

use commas to inherit directli in a class declaration


Here is very complete:

    class Generic extends String implements Implements1, Implements2 {}

    class Generic <T extends Class1 & Interface1 & Interface2> extends Class2 <W extends 

    Class3 & Iterface 5> implements Interface3, Interface4 {
            public <Q extends Class2 & Interface4, R extends Class4 & Interface6> Generic(T wtf, Q arg, R arg) { }
        }
```